# Доступ к сайтам в сети TOR

Tags: php, tor

Есть задача получить страницу сайта в сети tor на php 7.2, centos 7. Нашел такой код с curl:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://website.onion");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $code;
echo $result;
```

Пробовал разные его модификации, но всегда получаю в ответ код 0. Какой есть рабочий вариант?

Comment: соответствующий прокси то у вас есть на указанном порту?

Comment: @teran к сожалению, у меня недостаточно знаний в этой области, чтобы ответить

Comment: сам по себе курл не сможет получить доступ к тору. для этих целей вы указываете прокси. Указываете его на своем же сервере. Вам либо надо развернуть таковой прокси у себя, либо использовать публичный прокси.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15445285/1216425 вот тут например упоминают privoxy

Comment: @teran спасибо за наводку, буду разбираться!